# Making brightness work on Elementary OS Loki with fn key

Tags: display, keyboard-shortcuts, laptop, brightness, vaio

I'm a little new in Linux operative systems and I've been trying to make my laptop Vaio vpcee23el with Elementary OS (Loki) dim its backlight. I could found a way to make it in this question [Intel graphics change brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04) using the @Phoenix answer:

He explained that should add

```
sudo sh -c "echo x > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
sudo sh -c "echo y > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness" # (optional)
sudo sh -c "echo y > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1/brightness" # (optional)
```

> where 0 <= x <= 4882 and 0 <= y <= 10.

in /etc/rc.local file. When I tryed it, it worked, in fact, it worked even just using `sudo sh -c "echo x > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"` directly in terminal.

But I would like to know if there is any way to make this work along the fn key so I don't have to type it on terminal every time i want to change my laptop brightness.
s

Comment: The solution suggested by Darius worked for me. I have a Dell Vostro 15 with Intel integrated graphics. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

I found this: [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594068/fnf5-f6-keys-to-adjust-brightness-doesnt-work)

and this worked for me from his answer: [image: solved the problem]

P.S: I have asus too, but I got X550JX model.